# How to pass classes from components with already existing styles in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I have two components called `One.svelte` and `Two.svelte`

This is how `One.svelte` looks like:

```
<Two class="mt-8 border"/> //example tailwind classes
```

How `Two.svelte` looks like:

```
<main class="mt-6 bg-red-500">...</main>
```

I want the `main` element of `Two.svelte` to use the classes passed from the `One.svelte` without removing the existing classes on `Two.svelte` like `mt-6 bg-red-500` etc.

What I tried:

`Two.svelte`

```
<main class="mt-6 bg-red-500 {{$$props.class}}">...</main>
```

This does not seem to work, what is the right way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
<main class={`mt-6 bg-red-500 ${$$props.class}`}>
```

https://svelte.dev/repl/bb87bc86cc5c4fe0b7ba6472533af667?version=3.31.2